# ERD for a telephone tariffs website - is this optimal?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, web-applications, relational-database

I have designed database tables of Mobile Phones & Tariffs.

It should support multiple mobile networks, sale type and the related affiliate.

Points (for operators) are vary depending on the selected phone, tariff, network and sale Type.

**Example Price Plans:**

**T-Mobile**: *Consumer Upgrade*

- Samsung Galaxy S3
- Tariff: Super One (Monthly Cost: $12.00)
- This sale affiliate with 'Retailer One'
- Total Point: 3.3

**T-Mobile**: *Consumer New Connection*

- Samsung Galaxy S3
- Tariff: Super One (Monthly Cost: $35.00)
- This sale affiliate with 'Retailer Two'
- Total Point: 7.3

**AT&T**: 'Sim Only Deal' (Without Phone)

- Tariff: X-Deal Two (Monthly Cost: $18.00)
- This sale affiliate with 'Retailer One'
- Total Point: 10.0

See the tables design below, is this how it should be done? or how can it be improved?

**Database Design:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `affiliate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `affiliate` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Retailer One'),
(2, 'Retailer Two');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `network` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `network` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'T-Mobile'),
(2, 'AT&T');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `network_saletype` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `network_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `saletype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `network_saletype` (`id`, `network_id`, `saletype_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 3);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `phone` (`id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'Samsung Galaxy S3', ' Quad-core, NFC, AMOLED'),
(2, 'Apple iPhone 4S', 'A5 chip, 8MP camera, Siri voice');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phone_points` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tarrif_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `affilicate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `point` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `phone_points` (`id`, `phone_id`, `tarrif_id`, `affilicate_id`, `point`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, 3.3),
(2, 1, 2, 2, 7.3);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `saletype` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `saletype` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Consumer Upgrade'),
(2, 'Consumer New Connection'),
(3, 'Sim-Only Deal');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tariff_point` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tarrif_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `affilicate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `point` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `tariff_point` (`id`, `tarrif_id`, `affilicate_id`, `point`) VALUES
(3, 3, 1, 10);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tarrif` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `network_saletype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tariff_duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `monthly_cost` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `tarrif` (`id`, `network_saletype_id`, `name`, `tariff_duration`, `monthly_cost`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Super One', 12, '12.00', '200 Mins, 400 Texts, 500MB Internet'),
(2, 1, 'Super One', 12, '35.00', '200 Mins, 400 Texts, 500MB Internet'),
(3, 2, 'X-Deal Two', 12, '18.00', '');
```

**Result**

```
mysql> select * from network;
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | T-Mobile |
|  2 | AT&T     |
+----+----------+

mysql> select * from affiliate;
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Retailer One |
|  2 | Retailer Two |
+----+--------------+

mysql> select * from saletype;
+----+-------------------------+
| id | name                    |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | Consumer Upgrade        |
|  2 | Consumer New Connection |
|  3 | Sim-Only Deal           |
+----+-------------------------+

mysql> select * from network_saletype;
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | network_id | saletype_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 |           1 |
|  2 |          2 |           3 |
+----+------------+-------------+


  mysql> select * from tarrif;
+----+---------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------------------+
| id | network_saletype_id | name       | tariff_duration | monthly_cost | description                         |
+----+---------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------------------+
|  1 |                   1 | Super One  |              12 |        12.00 | 200 Mins, 400 Texts, 500MB Internet |
|  2 |                   1 | Super One  |              12 |        35.00 | 200 Mins, 400 Texts, 500MB Internet |
|  3 |                   2 | X-Deal Two |              12 |        18.00 |                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------------------+

mysql> select * from  tariff_point;
+----+-----------+---------------+-------+
| id | tarrif_id | affilicate_id | point |
+----+-----------+---------------+-------+
|  3 |         3 |             1 |    10 |
+----+-----------+---------------+-------+

mysql> select * from  phone;
+----+-------------------+---------------------------------+
| id | name              | description                     |
+----+-------------------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | Samsung Galaxy S3 |  Quad-core, NFC, AMOLED         |
|  2 | Apple iPhone 4S   | A5 chip, 8MP camera, Siri voice |
+----+-------------------+---------------------------------+

mysql> select * from phone_points;
+----+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| id | phone_id | tarrif_id | affilicate_id | point |
+----+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
|  1 |        1 |         1 |             1 |   3.3 |
|  2 |        1 |         2 |             2 |   7.3 |
+----+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
```

**Edit**: My question was is the relationship design between phone, tarrif, network and saleType is ok? Basically operator can select a retailer which then select Mobile Network.. then select what type of sale (eg: consumer upgrade) and then select phone with related related tariffs. Depending what tarrifs and/or phone they have selected - operator gets number of points.

Comment: Minor points, `affilicate_id` and `tarrif_id` are misspelt. Also, the tariff and product descriptions are holding CSV strings, and if you wanted to set up a comparison feature, you might want to break those down into further separate tables.

Comment: Oh thanks for letting me know about the misspelt.. I am aware about the tarrif descriptions, thanks. I don't need to break those down.

Comment: cross-posted on DBA.se http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24434/mobile-phone-tariffs

Comment: @bluefeet, thanks. OP, it's been netiquette for around 30 years not to cross-post without hyperlinking, since it risks creating duplicate effort. In my book it normally merits a downvote on SO, so please don't do it `:)`.

Comment: Can you please look at [this image](http://i.imgur.com/V8g1E.png) and tell me `tariff_point` fits in?

Comment: @njk That is nice, thanks for your time :) `tariff_point` link with `tarrif` table (The example if this is Sim Only Deal without Phone - see example above if you understood what I meant?)

Comment: @njk Are going to post answer?

Comment: @user791022 Was I supposed to?

Comment: @njk Sorry I thought you are because you asked me question where `tariff_point` fits in.. Let me know if the tables design is ok and can it be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This table implies that it's ok for 2 or 5 or 1,847 affiliates to have the same name.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `affiliate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

These inserts will work. They probably shouldn't.

```
INSERT INTO `affiliate` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Retailer One'),
(2, 'Retailer One'),
(3, 'Retailer One'),
(4, 'Retailer One'),
(5, 'Retailer One');
```

The problem is that, while you've defined a meaningless (surrogate) integer as a primary key, you haven't defined what that thing is a surrogate *for*. All those tables should have a unique constraint on *some* combination of columns besides the surrogate ID number.

You've also defined no foreign keys at all. This is almost certainly a mistake.

When insert statements like this succeed, you've got work to do.

```
insert into phone_points values (1078, 3000, 2743, 10234, -33344.03);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I never really got into habbit using foreign keys.. I have updated my question. Are they relationships is ok?

Comment: Are the relationships ok? No, not without foreign keys. In fact, without foreign key declarations, we don't know what *you* think the relationships *are*.